# TypeScript compiler does not recognize interface if service is injected at constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

The code is below.

chart-modal-interface.ts

```
export abstract class ChartModal {
    modalRef: ChartModalRef<any>;
    abstract onModalInit(data: ChartModalContext): void;
}
```

download-history-modal-component.ts

```
 export class DownloadHistoryModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ChartModal {
    public modalRef: ChartModalRef<any>;

    // error if service is injected
    constructor(private someService:SomeService) {}
    // ok if no service is injected
    // constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
    ngOnDestroy() {}
    onModalInit(data: ChartModalContext): void {}
}
```

chart-modal.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ChartModalService {
    public show(clazz: typeof ChartModal): void
    {
        // .....
    }
}
```

analysis.component.ts

```
export class AnalysisComponent {
    constructor(private chartModalService: ChartModalService) {}

    private onFinish(): void {
       this.chartModalService.show(DownloadHistoryModalComponent); // error here
    }
}
```

error message:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof DownloadHistoryModalComponent'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof ChartModal'.

My development environment:

> Angular6
>   TypeScript2.7.2
>   WebStorm2018.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are passing in a `typeof X` you are actually passing in the constructor of the class to the function. Since there is no constructor defined `ChartModal` has an empty constructor signature (`new () => ChartModal`). Since `DownloadHistoryModalComponent` defines a constructor with an argument ( `new someService:SomeService) => DownloadHistoryModalComponent`) it makes it incompatible with the signature for `ChartModal`.

If your intent is to accept any constructor that returns something that implements `ChartModal`, with any number of parameters you can use the following signature for the constructor:

```
public show(clazz: new (...args: any[]) => ChartModal): void
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your polite explanation! It works perfectly!